# Getting "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" when trying to access a URL param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql

I want to send a param value from my URL to my GraphQL request. This hard-coded value is working fine

```
import { getSdk } from "./generated/graphql";
      
const gqlClient = new GraphQLClient("http://localhost:3000/api/graphql");
      
function getProductParam() {
  return 2
}

export const { getBulbs } = getSdk(getProductParam(), gqlClient);
```

But when I try and add useRouter as so things go wrong

```
import { getSdk } from "./generated/graphql";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
      
const gqlClient = new GraphQLClient("http://localhost:3000/api/graphql");
      
function getProductParam() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { productId } = router.query;
    return productId
  }

export const { getBulbs } = getSdk(getProductParam(), gqlClient);
```

On the front end on the page component, I can copy the `getProductParam` function and console log out the `getProductParam` function and that also works just fine but when I send that value to the graphQL request I get:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the
> body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I can't understand why I am receiving these errors as my current understanding is as follows

- My hook useRouter seems to be in a function component
- I do not have mismatching versions of React and React DOM
- I don't have multiple versions of React in this app
- I don't think I'm breaking the rules of Hooks - this function isn't passed to a function using useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect or used in an event handler

I've got through the documentation and can't see what I'm doing wrong

If anyone can shed some light on what I've done wrong that would be great!

Comment: Hi Neil Kelsey! Did you check my below answer? Let me know please :)

Comment: I did! And it does work - it's not the solution I ended up with, for me a nicer solution was before this step in getServerSideProps getting the query value from context.query.productId then it's there available from the start - but your answer is the best answer for my question so I've marked it as correct - also helped with my understanding of why it wasn't working - thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a hook, `useRouter` in your case, only at the top level of a React component or of a custom hook, as [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) stipulates. And you are calling it inside `getProductParam` which is neither of them.

You could transform your GraphQL setup to a custom hook, something like:

```js
import { getSdk } from "./generated/graphql";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const gqlClient = new GraphQLClient("http://localhost:3000/api/graphql");

export const useGraphQLFunctions = () => {
  // works because it's called at the top level of a custom hook
  const router = useRouter();

  const { getBulbs } = getSdk(router.query.productId, gqlClient);

  return {
    getBulbs,
  };
};
```

And use it this way, for `getBulbs`, for example:

```js
import { useGraphQLFunctions } from "./useGraphQLFunctions";
export default function SomeComponent() {
 // works because it's called at the top level of a component
  const { getBulbs } = useGraphQLFunctions();

  // do something with getBulbs

  return <div></div>;
}
```